# dynamically create md-card from API response

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I'm making an API call and storing a bunch of user profiles, and I want to be able to dynamically create cards (Angular Material Design md-card) for each profile. The number of profiles returned can vary, so this needs to be dynamic.

This is my component file which makes the JSONP request and stores the profiles in the `profiles` variable:

```
import {Component, Injectable, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {Jsonp} from '@angular/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-staff',
  templateUrl: './staff.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./staff.component.css']
})
@Injectable()
export class StaffComponent implements OnInit {
  public searchField: string;
  apiRoot = 'this/is/my/api/url';
  public results: JSON;
  public profiles;

  constructor(private jsonp: Jsonp) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  setSearchField(field: string){ // ignore this method
    this.searchField = field;
    console.log('Received field: ' + this.searchField);
  }

  search(term: string) {
    const apiUrl = `${this.apiRoot}?search=${term}&rows=10&callback=JSONP_CALLBACK`;
    return this.jsonp.request(apiUrl).map(results => { this.results = results.json(); console.log(this.results['profiles'][0]); this.profiles = results['profiles']; return results.json(); });
  }

}
```

This is the template for the above component, where I'm trying to use `*ngFor` to create a list of `md-card`:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-md-auto">
      <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let profile of profiles">
          <md-card class="example-card">
            <md-card-header>
              <div md-card-avatar class="example-header-image"></div>
              <md-card-title>{{profile.fullName}}</md-card-title>
              <md-card-subtitle>Department</md-card-subtitle>
            </md-card-header>
            <img md-card-image src="../assets/image.png">
            <md-card-content>
              <p>
                This section of the card will contain information about the result being searched for. It could also be
                accompanied by additional information such as links.
              </p>
            </md-card-content>
            <md-card-actions>
              <button md-button>APPLY</button>
              <button md-button>GO TO xyz</button>
            </md-card-actions>
          </md-card>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My profiles data is in the form of an array (assume that the array doesn't exceed a length of 10) and takes the following form:

```
0: {fullName: "Foo Bar", emailAddress: "foobar@foobar.com", image: "/profile/image/foobar/foobar.jpg", phoneNumber: "99999999"},

1: {fullName: "Foo Bar1", emailAddress: "foobar1@foobar.com", image: "/profile/image/foobar1/foobar1.jpg", phoneNumber: "919999999"}
```

However, there are no `md-card`s being rendered. I have checked that `profiles` isn't empty. How do I dynamically create cards based on the number of profiles and populate the content with values from the profile objects?

Comment: how does your `profiles` data look like? cab you add that to your question?

Comment: @Faisal I have added more information about the `profiles` data in my question.

Comment: `this.profiles = results['profiles']` should be `this.profiles = this.results['profiles']` or `this.profiles = results.json()['profiles']`

Comment: @cyrix thanks for that, I've fixed that in the code now. However, there is still nothing being rendered. I've printed out the profiles array in the console to check that it isn't undefined.

Comment: a coponent cannot be @Injectable(). you have given @component and @Injectable() decoroter to the class. can you make sure that is not the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try to use a `BehaviorSubject` from `rxjs` and emit the profiles from  the response. In your template make use of the `async` pipe. This would make sure that angular's change detection would pick up the changes.

```
private readonly profiles$$ = new BehaviorSubject([]);
public readonly profiles$ = this.profiles$$.asObservable();

//  ...

search(term: string) {
  const apiUrl = `${this.apiRoot}?search=${term}&rows=10&callback=JSONP_CALLBACK`;
  return this.jsonp.request(apiUrl).map(res => {
    let results = res.json();
    this.profiles$$.next(results.profiles);
    return results;
  });
}
```

and in your template:

```
<li *ngFor="let profile of profiles$ | async">
  <!--  ... -->
</li>
```

Btw: Remove the `@Injectable` decorator from the component, components shouldn't be `injectable`.

Note: You should really consider moving the api call into a shared service, this would keep your component's logic clean and you could use it in other components too. Also you could inform yourself about the `redux` "pattern", for this you can look into `@ngrx/store` and `@ngrx/effects`. More information can be found at the [**@ngrx/platform**](https://github.com/ngrx/platform) monorepo. It will give you huge control about your application's state and it's easier to manage your data and control requests/responses from an external APIs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have tried your approach but I'm getting an error in the console. `Can't bind to 'ngForOr' since it isn't a known property of 'li'.` Please advise on how to proceed from here. I have removed the Injectable decorator from the component as well, that was a mistake.

Comment: I think you mean `'ngForOf' since it isn't a known property of 'li'`, did you import the `CommonModule` from  `@angular/common` in your module containing the component ?

Comment: No, the console error clearly says `'ngForOr'`. I have imported the `CommonModule`. Are you able to provide a plunker? I initially followed this tutorial in setting up my angular service, so feel free to use the API used in here: https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/http/jsonp-with-observables/

Comment: Angular has no `ngForOr` directive just a `ngForOf` directive, but could you add your module code which is declaring the component to your question please? The `ngForOr` error could acutally happen if you  typed `*ngFor="let profile or  profiles$ | async"` instead of `*ngFor="let profiles of profiles$ | async`, because angular "desugars" it into `let-profile [ngForOf]="profiles | async"`.

Comment: Oh yes, I accidentally typed `let profile or profiles$`. I have fixed that now. However, there is still nothing being rendered in terms of the `md-card`

Comment: Could you add `this.profiles$.subscribe(x => console.log(x));` into the `ngOnInit` and check if it's logging any values? And are there any errors in console?

Comment: It is not logging any values. An empty array is printed. However, I tried putting that statement inside the `return` clause and it seems to be printing the correct profile values. `onInit()` is only called on initialization so it will be empty. I have to invoke the API call using a search bar before the profiles are populated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153911/discussion-between-cyrix-and-user141834).

Answer (score 0):

Your result is processed into a map() and still returns `Observable|promise` So you need to handle the `async` behavior of the value coming from the server.

Angular provide a `async` pipe you can use in your template to say that when ever the data will come reflect it in my UI.

you can move your server call to a `@Injectable()` service which will return Observable and store that in your component variable and then in your UI you can simple use `async` pipe

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let profile of profiles | async">
      <md-card class="example-card">
        <md-card-header>
```

This works perfectly with Observable and http calls in angular api. when your angular loads, it finishes the template binding but the data from the server comes after that that is why your data does not reflect in UI. so you have to handle that async behavior. hope this helps :)

Comment: This won't work, because he's setting `profiles` inside the `map` call. Therefore `profiles` isn't an Observable.

Comment: ohh he is using profile! i thought he is using result. I will change my answer to point to result so that it will work

Comment: Sadly he's doing the api call inside his component and applying the result inside the `map` which propably causes  angular's change detection to not pick up the changes. But your answer would be correct if  `profiles` would be an Observable as in my aproach.

Comment: right, I initially thought that! thanks for pointing out that :)