# view not updating even when observable changes

Tags: angular

In one of my previous questions ([dynamically create md-card from API response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46045819/dynamically-create-md-card-from-api-response)), I dynamically create cards based on a number of responses from an API.

This is the service which makes API calls:

```
@Injectable()
export class WebSearchService {

  private readonly _results$$ = new BehaviorSubject([]);
  private readonly _isLoading$$ = new BehaviorSubject(false);

  public readonly results$ = this._results$$.asObservable().shareReplay();
  public readonly isLoading$ = this._isLoading$$.asObservable();

  public term: string;
  p: number; // page

  public config = {
    itemsPerPage: 10,
    currentPage: this.p,
    totalItems: 100
  };

  constructor(private http: Http){
  }

  search(term: string, page?: number){

    return this.http.get(`my/api/{term}`).do(response => {
      this._isLoading$$.next(false);
      this.config.totalItems = response.json().estimated_total;
      this.config.currentPage = this.p;
    })
      .map(response => response.json().results as WebResult[]).map(result => {
        this._results$$.next(result);
        this.term = term;
        return result;
      })
    .take(1);
  }

  updatePage(page: number){
    this.p = page;
    return this.search(this.term, page);
  }

}
```

The component which uses the results from the service:

```
export class ResultsComponent implements OnInit {
  private readonly _results$$ = new BehaviorSubject([]);

  public readonly isLoading$ = this.webService.isLoading$;
  public results$ =  this.webService.results$;
  p = 1; //

  constructor(public webService: WebSearchService) { }

  ngOnInit() { //
  }

  changePage(page: number){
    console.log('Page: ' + page);
    this.results$ = this.webService.updatePage(page);
  }
```

and the template:

```
<ng-template [ngIf]="isLoading$ | async" [ngIfElse]="results">
  is loading ...
</ng-template>

<ng-template #results>
  <div class="container-fluid" *ngFor="let result of results | paginate: this.webService.config">
    <!-- cards get dynamically created here -->
  </div>
</ng-template>
<pagination-controls *ngIf="(results$ | async)?.length>0" maxSize="6"
                     previousLabel=""
                     nextLabel=""
                     align="center"
                     (pageChange)="changePage($event)"
                     class="my-pagination"
                     screenReaderPaginationLabel="Pagination"
                     screenReaderPageLabel="page"
                     screenReaderCurrentLabel="You are on page"
                     autoHide="true"
></pagination-controls>
```

I have another component which calls the `search` method in the service. However, the view does not get updated if the search is invoked whilst on any page except page 1. E.g. If I go to page 3 of the results view, and then perform another search, then the `results$` observable gets updated, but the view remains on the old search results. I have to manually change to page 1 in pagination to get the new results. Is there any way to automatically refresh the view?

I have tried my best to explain the problem. The project is quite large so I am unable to create a plunkr but willing to explain/provide more code.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Well, to be honest... There are so many issues with your code that I would not even start with considering something as complicated as NgZone or ChangeDetectorRef - there's a ton of corrections that need to be made before those can really become an issue... But I don't really get what you're trying to do. For example - why there are so many BehaviorSubjects that you convert to observables? Is it not sufficient to just return http.get() mapped result? Are you trying to implement some kind of caching? And just a hint: your immediate problem is in the ResultsComponent.changePage() function.

Comment: Could you offer some suggestions or improvements?

Comment: Sure I can, but I need something to start with. I do not see what you're trying to do, so unless you give some insight into it I'll not be able to suggest anything meaningful. You're describing ***what*** and ***how*** you're doing - you created component A which talks to component B etc., while I ask for ***why*** you have created them this way and not another. I want to understand real-world task you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 3):

The `success` or `error` functions of your observable are most probably running out of the Angular zone which means Angulars change detection does not run when a new value is emitted. You can use [`ChangeDetectorRef`](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef) to run change detection manually when the value in question is updated.

```
constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {} // inject in your constructor

myObservable.subscribe(value => {
  this.myValue = value; // update out of scope
  this.cdr.detectChanges(); // run change detection manually
});
```

You can also try to manually subscribe the `results$` observable and update an instance variable every time a new value arrives. The instance variable is used for the ngFor directive. I removed everything not relevant from your code and added a quick example to demonstrate what I mean:

Your class:

```
export class ResultsComponent implements OnInit {
  private results$ =  this.webService.results$;
  public results = [];

  constructor(private webService: WebSearchService, private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {
    this.results$.subscribe(result => {
      this.results = result;
      this.cdr.detectChanges();
    });
  }
}
```

And your template:

```
<div *ngFor="let result of results | paginate: this.webService.config"></div>

<pagination-controls 
  *ngIf="results.length > 0" 
  maxSize="6" previousLabel="" 
  nextLabel="" 
  align="center" 
  (pageChange)="changePage($event)"
  class="my-pagination" 
  screenReaderPaginationLabel="Pagination" 
  screenReaderPageLabel="page" 
  screenReaderCurrentLabel="You are on page"
  autoHide="true">
</pagination-controls>
```

Comment: The view refreshes if I don't touch the pagination and stay on the first page. However, the problem occurs when i navigate to different pages, and then go on to change the search term. `results$` still receives the changes, but it is just not reflected in the view. I tried your suggestion and the problem remains.

Comment: Have you tried to manually subscribe the results$ observable (not with the async pipe) and to use an instance variable for the ngFor in your template which is updated every time results$ receives an update?

Comment: No I havent tried that. Could you provide an example using the code I have put above?

Comment: I'm getting an error on line 1 of my template, I have updated my answer to show the full template (with your suggested changes) so you can advise how I can continue from here.

Comment: Sorry, I completely forgot to include what the error was. ``Cannot read property 'instance' of undefined
    at nodeValue (core.es5.js:10324)
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (ResultsComponent.html:1)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (``

Comment: You did not change your code as I suggested, you added a template variable called „results“, now the observable is never subscribed.

Comment: Is there any way to do it with the template? I already had a template in my code previously but I thought it was not an important detail so didn't mention it in my question.

Comment: No you do not understand what I am saying. You should _not_ do the subscription in the template via the async pipe, you should try do do it manually so you have more control over what is happening.